# How to do auto increment primary keys onetomany create operation?

Tags: spring, jpa, jpa-2.0

Here `Customer_id` is join column. I have two tables customer and address in oneToMany relationship. For both have primary key are auto increment.

Few main points are:

1. OneToMany uni-direction relationship.
2. Primary keys in correspond tables are auto increments.
3. Problem in create new

In **Customer.java**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="customer_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
private long customerId;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="address", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="customer_id")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="account_id", referencedColumnName="account_id")})
private List<Address> addresses;
```

In **Address.java**

```
@Column(name="customer_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
private int   customerId;
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `customer_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `encrypt_key` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `create_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `self_description` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`),
  KEY `idx_last_name` (`last_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=101 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `address` (
  `account_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `address_type` varchar(15) NOT NULL,  -- Office, Branch-1, Branch-2, 
  `door_num` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `landmark` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `street` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `area_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `district` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `postal_code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `phone2` varchar(20),
  `create_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`),
  KEY `idx_fk_city` (`city`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_id` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`customer_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=201 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

While I am creating a new customer, but I am error like this.

> SqlExceptionHelper:144 - SQL Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000 2015-12-10
>   13:39:32 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:146 - Cannot add or update a child
>   row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mobily`.`address`, CONSTRAINT
>   `fk_customer_id` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer`
>   (`customer_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Because: `custmer_id` in `Address` object coming as '0'. but that is

`Customer` object before save. is this:

```
customer    Customer  (id=90)   
    active  1   
    addresses   ArrayList<E>  (id=95)   
        elementData Object[10]  (id=117)    
            [0] Address  (id=119)   
                accountId   0   
                addressType "main office" (id=121)  
                areaName    "area3" (id=122)    
                city    "city3" (id=123)    
                customerId  0   
                district    "district3" (id=124)    
                doorNum "89" (id=125)   
                landmark    "landmark3" (id=126)    
                phone1  "646432365465" (id=127) 
                phone2  "4534542355675" (id=128)    
                postalCode  "453245" (id=129)   
                street  "street3" (id=130)  
        modCount    1   
        size    1   
    customerId  0   
    email   "bbb@gmail.com" (id=104)    
    encryptKey  "wwwwwfsad" (id=109)    
    firstName   "xxx" (id=110)  
    lastName    "yyy" (id=111)  
    password    "user3" (id=112)    
    selfDescription "user3" (id=113)    
    theme   Theme  (id=114) 
    userName    "user3" (id=116)
```

Comment: Show your DAO code where you are trying to save the object.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the auto-increment from your SQL tables. And configure your model in this manner :

```
@Id
@Column(name = "primary_key_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "chat_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "chat_seq_gen", sequenceName = "chat_seq")
private Long chatid;
```

Then create a sequence called as chat_seq(For this class), and that should be it. Is this what you are looking for? If not, lemme know, I remove my answer.

*Edit*

Also in your Address.java, you should refer to Customer like this :

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "customerid", nullable = false)
private Customer customerAddresses;
```